# Display right datamember in the datagridview by using Bindinglist

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

Goal:

> Display Encapsulate field from Player

Problem:
Want to display `datamember_id`, `_name` and `_bust` in class `mainform` only by using `bindingList`

Was it suppose to use syntax `[]` above the encapsulate field?

---

```
Class MainForm

    dataGridViewPlayers.AutoGenerateColumns=true;
    dataGridViewPlayers.AutoSizeColumnsMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

    bindingSourcePlayers.Clear();

    bindingSourcePlayers.DataSource = _myGameManager.Players;




Class GameManager:

    public BindingList<Player> Players
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _myPlayerGUI_list.Count; i++)
            {
                _player.Add(new Player(_myPlayerGUI_list[i].Player));
            }
            return _player;
        }

    }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CardGameClassLibrary;

namespace CardGameLib
{
    public class Player
    {

        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private Hand _myHand;
        private int _win;
        private int _lost;
        private bool _madeMove = false;
        private bool _bust = false;


        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public Hand MyHand
        {
            get { return _myHand; }
            set { _myHand = value; }
        }

        public int Win
        {
            get { return _win; }
            set { _win = value; }
        }

        public int Lost
        {
            get { return _lost; }
            set { _lost = value; }
        }

        public bool MadeMove
        {
            get { return _madeMove; }
            set { _madeMove = value; }
        }

        public bool Bust
        {
            get { return _bust; }
            set { _bust = value; }
        }

        public Player(int pId)
        {
            _id = pId;

            _myHand = new Hand();
        }


        public Player(Player pPlayer)
        {
            _id = pPlayer.Id;
            //_name = pPlayer.Name;
            _name = "adsf";
        }


        public Player()
        {

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: You want to display only those properties in the datagridview, right?

Comment: You're right. datamember_id, _name and _bust only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Browsable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) attribute to prevent specific properties from being shown in the `DataGridView` when usin `BindingList`.

Example: if you want to hide `MadeMove`:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public bool MadeMove
{
    get { return _madeMove; }
    set { _madeMove = value; }
}
```